# first eigen value of Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

Let $\Omega$ be a region or a manifold, consider the Laplacian operator with Dirichlet condition. Let $\lambda_1>0$ be the first eigen value.

**Q** Why the $\lambda_1$ is simple, i.e. any two
eigenfunctions of the first eigenvalue must be
proportional?

Comment: Have you proved that first eigenfunctions are strictly positive?

Comment: Sorry I do not follow.

Comment: I mean the following fact: if $u$ is a first eigenfunction, i.e. $\Delta u + \lambda_1 u = 0$ and $u|_{\partial \Omega} = 0,$ then $u>0$ on the interior of $\Omega$.

Comment: I see, but I did not prove this. And I also did not know this FACT.

Comment: What is your background? It's hard to know how to answer this question usefully without some context. Do you know about the analyticity of eigenfunctions? The variational characterization of eigenvalues in terms of the Rayleigh quotient? If not, there's no quick way to prove this. Regardless, you're probably best off finding a good reference - you can find this proved as a  theorem in the section *Eigenvalues of Elliptic Operators* of Jost's *Partial Differential Equations*.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I have seen in someone' talk:  consider $\Delta\frac{\phi_2}{\phi_1}+\nabla\log\phi_1\cdot\nabla\frac{\phi_2}{\phi_1}=0$, here $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are two eigen solutions  w.r.t $\lambda$. But,  I did not follow the formula.

Comment: This formula is almost true (I think there's a factor of 2 missing), but I'm not sure how it's meant to help: the fact that $\lambda$ is the *first* eigenvalue needs to be used somehow, and the only way I know to do that is using the variational formulation.